Proof verification: $B\setminus(B\setminus A) = A\cap B$
Here is my proof:
Let $x\in B\setminus(B\setminus A).$ By repeated use of definitions, we get $$x\in B \wedge (x\notin B\setminus A) \iff x\in B \wedge\neg(x\in B\setminus A) \iff  x\in B \wedge\neg(x\in B\wedge x\notin a). $$ By DeMorgan’s law and the distributive law, $$x\in B \wedge (x\notin B \vee x\in A)\iff (x\in B\wedge x\notin B)\vee(x\in B \wedge x\in A).$$ Since $(x\in B\wedge x\notin B)$ is a contradiction, we have $\neg(x\in B\wedge x\notin B)$. By disjunctive syllogism,
$$(x\in B \wedge x\in A)\iff x\in A\cap B. \blacksquare$$
Since I am studying pure math on my own, (I have started with real analysis…) I would like to hear any feedback.

The proof is correct, you have shown an element is one set if and only if it's in the other. That's how it's done.

You don't need to consider elements at all. You can derive this using the definitions and the distributive laws.  $B\setminus (B\setminus)A = B\cap\lnot (B\cap\lnot A)= B\cap (\lnot B\cup A) = (B\cap\lnot B)\cup (B\cap A)=B\cap A$

Perhaps simpler is
$$B = [ ~B \cap A ~] \cup [ ~B \cap (\neg A) ~] $$
$$= [ ~B \cap A ~] \cup [ ~B \setminus A ~]. \tag1 $$
Note that in (1) above, $~B~$ has been partitioned as the union of two mutually exclusive (i.e. non-intersecting) sets.
Then
$$B \setminus [ ~B \setminus A ~]$$
$$= \{ ~[ ~B \cap A ~] \cup [ ~B \setminus A ~] ~\} \setminus [ ~B \setminus A ~]. \tag2 $$
Note that the expression in (2) above has the form
$$[ ~C \cup D ~] \setminus D \tag3 $$
where $~C~$ and $~D~$ are mutually exclusive, which implies that the expression in (3) above equals $~[ ~C ~]$.
Similarly, the expression in (2) equals $~[ ~B \cap A ~].$

$~\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
It is unclear whether the above analysis will be considered valid by the math professor teaching the corresponding course.  If the problem composer's intent was to force the student to correctly use specific laws, such as DeMorgan's law and the distributive law, then the analysis might well be regarded as invalid.
On the other hand, math analysis is generally incremental in that you use simple results as building blocks to prove more complicated results.
So, the assumption that I made as to the evaluation in (3) could be converted into a preliminary lemma.
Similarly, the partitioning of $~B~$ into the union of two mutually exclusive sets could also be converted into a preliminary lemma.
This way, you are (in effect) avoiding having to re-invent the wheel.  That is, you are avoiding having to use very simple tools (i.e. DeMorgan's law, the distributive law) when attacking more complicated expressions.

So technically you say my proof is correct, but I should use properties of sets instead of using propositional calculus.... Also I am learning by self study. Thank you.

@Akash Except that should is a little strong.  Perhaps more appropriate to say that you should (in general) consider this type of approach.  For example, if the expression to be evaluated had been significantly more complicated, that would be a stronger argument (for such a problem) in favor of the building blocks approach.

Thanks again, but I have a doubt, how to think of these lemmas in general, like it's true but it's difficult to come up with.... Does it come with practice?? Also what does $\neg A$ mean? Is it the complement of the set or does it mean $x \notin A$?

@Akash Yes, it comes with practice.  I instinctively knew that $$B = [ ~B \cap A ~] \cup [ ~B \cap (\neg A) ~],$$ without thinking, because of my exposure to similar problems.

@Akash $~\neg A~$ means not in $~A~$ which means the negation of $~A.$

For example, to prove $(A\setminus B)\cap(B \setminus A)=\emptyset$, can I use the building blocks approach? Or is it possible to use another method? If so I would be grateful if you provide me with a hint…

@Akash If you mean proving that $$(A \setminus B) \cap (B \setminus A) = \emptyset,$$ I don't see how.  If you mean proving that assertion and then using that assertion as a building block to attack more complicated assertions : yes, if you happen to be working a problem where this preliminary conclusion is pertinent.

@Akash As far as solving the actual problem, you need to make this a separate MathSE posted question.  For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

The idea of a complementary set $\neg A$ requires some universal set $X$ that all sets in consideration are assumed to be subsets of. Otherwise “everything not in $A$” isn't a set.

@MatthewLeingang True, but you can construe $~B \cap (\neg A)~$ to represent all elements that are in $~B~$ and simultaneously are not in $~A.$  So, with this statement negation (rather than set negation) approach, no universal set is needed.  You simply need a framework that accepts that set $~A~$ exists.

Sure, you've just recapitulated the definition of $B \setminus A$.

Your proof looks valid to me. The problem I have with proofs written this way is they exchange one set of symbols (set theory operations) with another (boolean algebra operations). And in doing so they become almost too dense to read. I prefer to write them out more or less in English, as in:
Suppose $x \in B \setminus (B \setminus A)$. Then $x \in B$ and $x \notin B \setminus A$. If $x \notin A$, then the fact that $x \in B$ would give us that $x \notin B \setminus A$, contradicting what we know. So we must have that $x \in A$. Since $x \in B$ too, we know $x \in A \cap B$. Therefore $B\setminus (B \setminus A) \subseteq A \cap B$.
Now suppose that $x \in A \cap B$. Then $x \in A$ and $x \in B$. Because $x \in B$ and $x \in A$, we know $x \notin B \setminus A$. Since $x \in B$ and $x \notin B \setminus A$, we know $x \in B\setminus (B \setminus A)$. Therefore $A \cap B \subseteq B\setminus (B \setminus A)$.

Yes I have seen that's how it's done. I have read a book on proof writing and I have started on real analysis with Tao's and he suggests the same. Thank you.
